# Matching code with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

For my application, I want to match an URL with mod_rewrite such that the URL is passed directly to the file (index.php) through a GET request. This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1
```

However, it's not working, and it appears to indeterminately rewrite it as "index.php?q=index.php". Could anyone enlighten me on this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

try this one example

Comment: hey, thanks for replying, but it looks like that code isn't going to pass the URL as an argument to the php file. do you know how it would be possible to change something like `http://domain.com/user/example to http://domain.com/index.php?q=/user/example` ?

Comment: UPD. I've just combine our examples))) it wont call index.php?q=index.php because of RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f this very condition